# How do i insert the next value for an auto increment filed duing Prepared Statemenet insert operation?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using Mysql as database

```
mysql> desc customer;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| customer_id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

PreparedStatement insertpsmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into customer values(?)");
insertpsmt.setInt(1, "testname");
```

How do i insert the value for customer_id  as  this is a auto_increment field ??

Comment: If database is taking care of incrementing value for `customer_id`, then you do not have to write any code for that.

Comment: So you mean to say that i need to increment only the name filed ??

Comment: In you java side if database is taking care of incrementing value. In mysql, I am not sure how does `auto_increment` works. E.g. in Oracle a trigger is used for incrementing sequence and thus value will be populated.

Comment: if all you do is put in a name in your insert the id will be created auto incremented. you don't need to put in an id

Answer (score 1):

Specify the field names on your insert:-

```
PreparedStatement insertpsmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES(?)");
insertpsmt.setInt(1, "testname");
```

Or if you want to list the auto increment field (I quite often do) you can give it a value of NULL.

```
PreparedStatement insertpsmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer(customer_id, name) VALUES(NULL, ?)");
insertpsmt.setInt(1, "testname");
```